# Using a concatenade columns as key in merge. Pandas

Tags: pandas, merge

I was traying two concatenade two columns two create a key and merge two tables.

I resolved as follow.

Answer (score 0):

```
df1.merge(df2, left_on=(df1["column1"].astype(str)+df1["column2"].astype(str)), right_on='column3')
```